# Show in console sed /a edits

Tags: bash, sed

When doing substitutions this works:

`sed -i "s/yes/no/w /dev/stdout" myfile`

to display only the modified string, if any substitution occurs.
But I'd like to get the same report with /a, and I can't find a way to do it:

```
sed -i "/yes/a\hello w /dev/stdout" myfile
```

It just adds a new line with 'hello w /dev/stdout' to the file... I tried a few other variations with \w for example, but it just appends everything I add there.

Can it be done, having /a report matches?

By the way, /a doesn't seem to take any parameters, how would I make it global for example?

I guess I could use s/ and replace the match with itself plus the new line... but it feels like an ugly workaround.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible because the commands such a `a`,`i`,`c` and `=` place their values directly into the output stream whereas commands such as `y` and `s` only affect the pattern space. The pattern space is placed in the output stream once all sed commands have completed and the line ending is re-attached. Inspection of the source should confirm this. Work-arounds should use `s/^/inserted line\n/w /dev/stdout` or `s/$/\nappended line/w /dev/stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works, I tested it on `GNU sed`, not sure if syntax works for other versions as well

```
$ seq 3 > ip.txt

$ sed -i -e '/2/{a\hello' -e 'w /dev/stdout' -e '}' ip.txt
2
$ cat ip.txt 
1
2
hello
3
```

- `{}` can be used to group commands to perform for particular address
- multiple `-e` allows to combine multiline commands in single line

without `-e`

```
$ sed -i '/2/{a\hello
w /dev/stdout
}' ip.txt
2
```

Comment: Its exactly as you indicated - in fact 'hello' is added after the '2', but I want a confirmation that 'hello' was added, not that '2' was found. The output is showing the search string '2' and I'm looking for 'hello'.

Comment: well, I do not know a way to do that with sed... `2` will be printed only if `hello` is getting added...